# Como imprimir las combinaciones?

Tags: array, c, recursión

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo este programa en donde ya pude encontrar el numero de combinaciones que existe, pero me gustaria visualizar no el numero en general, sino **todas las combinaciones que hay en ese número**.

Alguien que en base a su experiencia y sus conocimientos me podría ayudar porfavor.

Tiene que ser el problema con recursividad de preferencia.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

// Recursividad

int factorial(int x);//prototipo
int main(){
int n,r,w;

printf("\n ***Programa para calcular las combinaciones***\n ");
printf("\n Ingresa la cantidad total de elementos:");
scanf("%i",&n);

printf("\nIngresa la cantidad de elementos de cada grupo:");
scanf("%i",&r);

w=factorial(n)/(factorial(r)*factorial(n-r));
printf("\n \n El numero de combinaciones es:%i\n \n ", w);



system("pause");
return 0;
}
//funcion factorial
int factorial(int x){
int respuesta;
if(x==0){
    respuesta=1;
} else{
    respuesta=x*factorial(x-1);
}
return (respuesta);
}
```

Comment: Como que tipo de elementos? Letras? Números? Si puedes poner un ejemplo de la salida que esperas y lo que haz intentado, ayudaría mucho.

Comment: @Cuauhtli Mira es que mi problema dice "Escriba un programa que despliegue todas las combinaciones de 5 archivos en tres carpetas, el total de combinaciones son 243, vease libros de combinatoria" La verdad no entiendo mucho, pero te dejo una imagen ahí arriba en el texto que me dan como ejemplo.